# Silex Routing to Controllers

Tags: model-view-controller, controller, routes, silex

Building an app with Silex using the MVC pattern. I'm having a bit of an issue in regards to what i should be doing after i have a route collection.

Here is my bootstrap for the app:

```
    <?php
namespace App;

use Igorw\Silex\ConfigServiceProvider;
use Silex\Application as Silex;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;


class Bootstrap extends Silex
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this['debug'] = true;

        $this->registerDefaultParameters();
        $this->registerDefaultServices();
        $this->registerRoutes();

    }

    protected function registerDefaultParameters()
    {
        $paths = isset($this['base_path']) ? $this['base_path'] : array();

        if (!isset($paths['base'])) {
            $paths['base'] = realpath(__DIR__ . '/../');
        }

        $defaults = array(
            'config' => $paths['base'] . '/App/Config',
            'twig.path' => $paths['base'] . '/public/themes/base/templates'
        );

        foreach ($defaults as $key => $value) {
            if (!isset($paths[$key])) {
                $paths[$key] = $value;
            }
        }

        $this['paths'] = $paths;
    }

    protected function registerDefaultServices()
    {
        $this->register( new ConfigServiceProvider($this['paths']['config'] . "/Services.yml") );

        foreach($this['services'] as $serviceName => $serviceData)
        {
            $this->register( new $serviceData['class'],(array_key_exists('parameters',$serviceData)) ? $serviceData['parameters'] : array() );
        }

    }

    protected function registerRoutes()
    {
        $this->register( new ConfigServiceProvider($this['paths']['config'] . "/Routes.yml") );

        $collection = new RouteCollection();
        foreach($this['routes'] as $key => $value)
        {
            $collection->add( $key, new Route(
                $value['path'],
                $value['defaults'],
                array(),
                array(),
                null,
                null,
                $value['methods']
            ));
        }

        $this['routes'] = $collection;
    }
}
```

So as you can see i set up some default params. I also load in my services from a YAML file which works fine.
I then register my routes again from a YAML file. I loop over each route in the YAML file and add the route to a RouteCollection and then re-store that in the apps ['routes'] entity.

So i end up with $this['routes'] being an instance of 'RouteCollection' with all my routes as 'Route' instances within it.

Now i want to set up all my controllers for the routes. My issue is i want to set up the product as modularized as possible. So instead of having a controllers folder and models folder containing all controllers and all models i want to have a Core folder with all the core modules in it e.g. a Base Module, a Page Module and a Contact Module. Each module has its own controllers models views etc. Very similar to how the Magento core is.

So my question is:

Now i have my routes set up, what steps do i need to take in order to make my routes instantiate the correct controller and action?

I need this to be dynamic so would rather not declared each individual controller.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my routing function to look like this:

```
protected function registerRoutes()
{
    $this->register( new ConfigServiceProvider($this['paths']['config'] . "/Routes.yml") );

    $routes = $this['config.routes']; // See the first key in the yaml file for this name
    foreach ($routes as $name => $route)
    {
        $this->match($route['pattern'], $route['defaults']['_controller'])->bind($name)->method(isset($route['method'])?$route['method']:'GET');
    }
}
```

Everytime the app runs it tries to match one fo the loaded routes and automatically passes it to the controller!